# MySQL Events in information system into programming language

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have 3 tables:

```
Users:
+----+-------------+
| id | nickname    |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Don2Quixote |
|  2 | Pechenye    |
|  3 | Maryana     |
|  4 | Luman       |
|  5 | Tester      |
+----+-------------+
Matches:
+----+----------+---------------------+
| id | owner_id | match_end_timestamp |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 |          1610698498 |
|  2 |        2 |          1610699911 |
|  3 |        3 |          1610701672 |
|  4 |        1 |          1610711211 |
|  5 |        1 |          1610725289 |
+----+----------+---------------------+
matches_players:
+----------+------+-------------+---------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
| match_id | team | slot_number | user_id |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+----------+------+-------------+---------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|        1 |    1 |           1 |       1 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|        2 |    1 |           2 |       2 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
...........................................                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|        3 |    1 |           1 |       3 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+----------+------+-------------+---------+
```

`match_end_timestamp` is future timestamp. My goal is to get event in programming language on reaching this date and send notification to each player in table `matches_players` where `match_id` is id of just ended match. Is it possible? Or the only solution is to store additional timer in my programming language in RAM?

Comment: Notify how?....

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry, didn't explained. They can be connected via websockets and subscribed on updates by their ID.

Comment: MySQL won't notify somebody, it have no such service. Poll the table from outside (from some client script/application) and notify users.

Comment: You can set up a job or an event to run at specified times.  Alternatively, you could use a queuing mechanism to trigger an action at the exact time.

Comment: @Akina the problem is I need high accuracy and I think it's not correct to poll the large table each second